# how to tell if address bar url has a certain sequence (php)

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, explode, address-bar

My address bar looks like this when the page is loaded-

```
index.php?search=_kfdTourDate:equal:2017-04-15|_kfnTourID:equal:14
```

If I make a search my address bar looks like this-

```
index.php?search=_kfnTourID:equal:2|_kfdTourDate:equal:2017-04-15|nFOC:bigger_equal:1|
```

or like this-

```
index.php?search=nTotalPrice:equal:99|tGuestName:equal:John|
```

I would like to run a function if only address url is in following format-

```
?search=_kfdTourDate:equal:xxxxxxxx|_kfnTourID:equal:xxxxxxxx|
```

If the url format is as follows it shouldn't run the function-

```
?search=_kfnTourID:equal:xxxxxxxx|_kfdTourDate:equal:xxxxxxxx|
```

or

```
?search=_kfdTourDate:equal:xxxxxxxx|_kfnTourID:equal:xxxxxxxx|tGuestName:equal:John|
```

I tried to do use `$IsSearch = explode(":",$_GET['search'] );` but couldn't make it work.

I would appreciate if you can show me the way to achieve this. Thank you all.

Comment: Is this on apache? The web server may need to be configured to support certain reserved characters... otherwise, you should encode the search string in the query string. Alternative is to POST the search.

Comment: you must explode using | first to get each parts

Comment: Also, if using `explode`, you need to set limits, in case people search with ":" or "|" strings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
if(count(array_filter(explode('|',$_GET['search'])))==2 && strpos($_GET['search'],'_kfdTourDate:equal:') ==0){

 echo "Yes";  // call your function here
}
```

***Output (In your given three scenario):-***

1. https://eval.in/776637
2. https://eval.in/776642
3. https://eval.in/776644

Comment: wooaww! Thank you very much.

Comment: @hijacker83  glad to help you.:):)

Comment: Cannot thank you enough. Really appreciate it. Everyday learning something new :)